# ¿Cómo hago para pasar variables entre funciones? en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Digamos que yo, tengo cierta función llamada name, con una variable dentro que sea una lista, digamos que la lista num[1,2], y nosotros queremos dar esta lista  a otra función, como hacemos ¿Cómo para pasarla como parámetro?

Este es el codigo en python (bastante sencillo), pero es una duda que como principiante, aún teniendo varios meses de experiencia no me queda totalmente claro:

```
def main():


    lista = [1,2]

    sum(suma)

def sum():

    suma = 0

    for i in lista:

        suma  += i

    return(suma)
    


main()
```

En este pequeño programa vemos la lista que ha sido declarada en la función main, pero tengo absoluto desconocimiento de como usar esta variable en otra función, seguramente sea una tontería, pero me aclararí el paso de parámtros entre funciones. Muchas gracias por su atención!

Answer (score 1):

En Python, por defecto cuando una variable se crea **fuera** de una función, se considera **global** por lo que puede usarse en cualquier parte del código:

```
x = "mundo"

def myfunc():
  print("Hola " + x)

myfunc()
```

Cuando se crea **dentro** de una función, se considera **local** y solo puede usarse dentro de esa función. Por ejemplo, el siguiente código te dará error porque `x` no existe como variable global, solo como local:

```
def myfunc():
  x = "mundo"
  print("Hola " + x)

myfunc()

print("Hola " + x)
```

Pero existe otra opción, que es definir una variable local como global. Es decir, la creas dentro de una función pero especificas que va a ser de tipo global con la instrucción `global`:

```
def myfunc():
  global x
  x = "mundo"
  print("Hola " + x)

myfunc()

print("Hola " + x)
```

Este último código, aunque `x` se haya creado como variable local dentro de una función, se ha especificado que va a ser global, con lo que puede usarse en cualquier parte del código de ahora en adelante.

> [Global
> variables](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp)

Entonces, con todo esto en mente, prueba tu código así:

```
def main():
    global lista
    lista = [1,2]
    sum(suma)

def sum():
    suma = 0
    for i in lista:
        suma  += i
    return(suma)
    
main()
```

Y ya por último, entiendo que como estás aprendiendo Python estás haciendo códigos sencillos (y eso está fenomenal, yo hago lo mismo) pero que sepas que puedes sumar todos los valores de una lista sin necesidad de hacer un bucle:

`sum(lista)` te devolverá la suma de la lista entera:

> [Función sum()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-function-python/)

Comment: muchas gracias!! Ya lo había solucionado y lo iba a responder ahora mismo, pero muchas gracias igualmente, aprecio tu tiempo mucho.

Comment: @SershRX Siempre puedes poner tu solución hallada para que sirva como respuesta a futuros lectores :)  [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer! muchas gracias por el consejo!

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente para pasar variables entre funciones, vamos a asignar a un parámetro a una función, por ejemplo, si tenemos la función de suma(numbers), el parámetro numbers equivaldrá a lo que nosotros le pasemos como parámetro más tarde a la función. El ejemplo aquí:

```
def main():

    lista = [1,2,3,4]

    print(suma(lista))

def suma(numbers):

    suma = 0

    for i in numbers:

        suma += i

    return suma



main()
```

Nosotros en la función main tenemos la variable de lista que contiene en si, los numeros [1,2,3,4], entonces podemos decir que lista equivale a [1,2,3,4].

Y en la funcion de suma, debemos crear un parámetro que pueda ser equivalente a la lista de nuestra función main.

Entonces para generar esta equivalencia necesitaremos introducir el parametro que queremos que equivalga a otro, que en nuestro caso es numbers, y lo introducimos también como parámtro en nuestra función suma entre los parentesis, para entendernos mejor, main(#Variable a ser equivalente a otra#), en este caso nosotros generaremos equivalencia entre lista y numbers, por lo tanto nuestra función de suma deberá quedar así suma(numbers); con esto le estamos diciendo a suma, que cuando llamemos a la función suma desde cualquier otro lugar, e introduzcamos un numero, variable o demás en forma de parámetro, por ejemplo suma(parámetro), nuestro parámetro introducido va a hacer equivalencia con numbers.

Basicamente suma(#Parámetro introducido por ejemplo con valor 1#) hace que numbers sea igual que parámetro introducido.